# How to make vim go to last line last character and then in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I have a few text files, each for its own purposes. *(Like: download.txt, questions.txt, word-meaning.txt etc.)*

**`questions.txt`**:

I put all my question, doubt approaching in my mind to this file to ask/clear when I go online *(I've no access to internet everytime of the day)*. I delete that line from the file when I ask that question.

**`download.txt`**:

I keep names of all packages or zipballs or tarballs in this file and download when I am connected.

**`word-meaning.txt`**:

I am not a native English speaker, so whenever I see any word which's meaning I don't in my native language, I write that down in this file and use Google Translate to translate it to my native language when I am connected.

In all above cases I have to go to last line of the file everytime I have to add anything to those lists.

### My Question:

Can I make vim go to line line, last character of the file and then go in in insert mode? I will alias that to something like `vimll` to use it with these type of files.

> Similar Question:
>
> [How do I start vim in insert mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11464088/939986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in terminal:

```
vim filename.ext +$ +starti!
```

To go to the last line, last character of the file `filename.ext` and then in insert mode.

You can also alias that for your convenience of use, so add the following in your `.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias vimll='vim +$ +starti!'
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might like using `$pu_` instead of `$`.

Comment: @kev not setting `$` won't let vim go to last line.

Comment: Type `vim --help`, You will see `+    Start at end of file`

Answer (score 2):

You can define an autocmd to go into insert mode at the end of the file whenever one of your files is loaded into a Vim window:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter questions.txt,download.txt,word-meaning.txt $|startinsert!
```

Comment: Instead of `$` one can use `$pu_` to start Insert mode on a newly inserted empty line at the very end of the file.