# GVIM : Possible to begin editing the file without having to press "i"?

Tags: vim

I am trying to move from GEDIT to GVIM but I noticed that when I open a file I am not free to edit it.

unless I press <kbd>i</kbd> to go in (INSERT) mode.

Is there a way to bypass this? So the file is instantly editable?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464088/how-do-i-start-vim-in-insert-mode

Comment: If you want to do this, there's no point in switching from gedit in the first place. (Why do you bother switching accounts so much when your others haven't even been banned yet?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by editing your .vimrc file. It looks like [set im!](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Start_in_insert_mode_without_losing_your_escape_key) is the command you're looking for to set input mode as the default, but you'll also need to explicitly map escape to change to command mode.

A better question is *why* you would want to do this, though. Unless you're opening a brand new file, once you know vim, you'll probably spend very little time in insert mode, as you should be using more advanced command-mode commands (append, correct, etc) to edit and update your code at the appropriate places. If you're just going to use vim the same way you use gedit, don't bother - gedit is better than vim at being gedit.

EDIT: After reading the comments on your question, it sounds like you really, really shouldn't be using vim. It's not something you want to stumble into by default, certainly not if what you want is a basic editor with customizable display.